# Script on Ending Process according to memory consumption windows 10

Tags: windows-10, powershell, batch

I am looking for a batch or powershell script that if memory used by a process is less than 10 MB end that process and restart it.I tried searching a lot,but i could not find a ultimate solution.

This is the script i tried but it doesn't work. Please help, thanks!

```
:start
@ECHO OFF
SET procName=iexplorer.exe
SET RAMLimit=10240
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%F IN ('tasklist^|findstr %procName%') DO SET foundString=%%F
FOR /F "tokens=5" %%F IN ("%foundString%") DO SET RAMConsumption=%%F
IF %RAMConsumption% LEQ %RAMLimit% && ping 8.8.8.8 -n 6 | FIND /I "out"
if errorlevel 0 (
TASKKILL /IM %procName%
) else (
echo iexplorer is working
)
goto start
```

Comment: you won't get an answer to a question like this, because superuser is not a free script writing service. Please show us your research and what problems you had implementing it, then we're glad to help.

Comment: i have added the script i tried.Thanks for advice.

Comment: **Less** than 10MB? I can understand wanting to restart processes which take up too much memory, but not too little. What are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would be a PowerShell Solution:

```
Get-Process iexplore -ea 0 | where { $_.PM -le 10MB } | foreach {
    $Path = $_.Path
    [bool]$Ping = Test-Connection 8.8.8.8 -Quiet
    if ($Path -and $Ping) {
        Stop-Process $_ -Force
        Start-Process $Path
    }
}
```

first, it looks for all `iexplore` processes, then it filters in `where` all processes which have less or equal to 10MB RAM Consumption. For Each process that matched the `where`, it stops and re-starts the process

Edit: it looks like you want to run this in an infinite loop, if so, just wrap your script in a `while` loop like this

```
while ($true) {
    Get-Process iexplore -ea 0 | where { $_.PM -le 10MB } | foreach {
        $Path = $_.Path
        [bool]$Ping = Test-Connection 8.8.8.8 -Quiet
        if ($Path -and $Ping) {
            Stop-Process $_ -Force
            Start-Process $Path
        }
    }
    sleep -s 1
}
```

if there's no path:

```
while ($true) {
    Get-Process iexplore -ea 0 | where { $_.PM -le 10MB } | foreach {
        [bool]$Ping = Test-Connection 8.8.8.8 -Quiet
        if ($Ping) {
            Stop-Process $_ -Force
            Start-Process iexplore
        }
    }
    sleep -s 1
}
```

Comment: Thanku sir.Thanks a lot.i am almost there but there is some problem with ur script.I wanted to check for a process continuosly that if the memory gets  less than 10 MB the application restarts.The process is getting restarted as per ur script.but if the memory used is more than 10 MB than its getting stucked.And last thing sir i want to also add a condition that restart the process only if less than 10 MB and internet is working.Like when this ping 8.8.8.8 is true.I could do  cmd but i dont know mucj=h in powershell.THANKS SIR.

Comment: @Frankruss I added some logic, does it work properly now?

Comment: Sir thanks for ur support.I wanted that if both condition is true i.e. memory less than 10MB and internet does not work then only restart the process.Ur logic restarts the process only if internet is working and memory condition is true.but when i disconnect the internet it closes the process but does not restart it again.THANKS.

Comment: @Frankruss ok, now it should behave the way you want it to. even though i did not understand the internet part. it would restart now if ping can reach 8.8.8.8. if you want to restart if ping does NOT reach 8.8.8.8, change `if ($Path -and $Ping)` to `if ($Path -and !$Ping)`

Comment: Now the script is not even restarting the process whether internet is working or not.

Comment: @Frankruss for me it works perfectly. it only does something, if there is/is not an internet connection, and if the process has a Path property. if you run `Get-Process iexplore | select Path` is the path empty or not? if it's empty, you could use the new one I put into answer. I mean it's a pretty dumb script, there's not much that can go wrong here, if you implement it exactly the way i wrote it in my answer. Are you getting any error message?

Comment: THNKS SIR.It is working now.